# Fetching file from remote server to local using Ansible script

Tags: ansible

Ansible automated script:

```
tasks:
     - name:  copying catalina.out to /tmp/jagthish location
       fetch:
          src:
            - yes
            - /usr/tomcat/tomcat8/logs/catalina.out
          dest: /tmp/jagthish/
```

error message:

> An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
>   fatal: [ip]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}

I tried to copy a file (`catalina.out`) from remote server to my local server. it shows above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't provide a list to the `src` argument of [`fetch` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/fetch_module.html). It expects a path to a file in a string.

You seem to want this:

```
- name:  copying catalina.out to /tmp/jagthish location
  fetch:
    src: /usr/tomcat/tomcat8/logs/catalina.out
    dest: /tmp/jagthish/
    flat: yes
```

Comment: - name:  copying catalina.out to /tmp/jagthish location
  fetch:
    src: /usr/tomcat/tomcat8/logs/catalina.out
    dest: /tmp/jagthish/
    
I tried this command previously. but it copies the entire directory /usr. i want to copy that (catalina.out) file only.

Comment: am executing all commands in playbook only. problem is it copying the entire directory. for copy module it works. but fetch module am facing this issue.

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/fetch_module.html . yes i understand the fetch module manual . It states that it copy only file not directory. now also i executed But it copies the entire directory. in local machine this entire directory is copied /tmp/jagthish/ip/usr/tomcat/tomcat8/logs/calalina.out.am expecting only catalina.out file.

Comment: You can't have a directory and file with the same name at the same time. Provide the correct path.

Comment: in remote machine catalina.out file location is /usr/tomcat/tomcat8/logs .. in logs directory catalina.out file is there.  this is the path you asking?